# Image understanding - CNN Triplet loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

i'm new to NN and trying to create a simple NN for image understanding.

I tried using the triplet loss method, but keep getting errors that made me think i'm missing some fundamental concept.

My code is :

```
def triplet_loss(x):
  anchor, positive, negative = tf.split(x, 3)

  pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1)
  neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)

  basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), ALPHA)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)

  return loss


def build_model(input_shape):
  K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')

  positive_example = Input(shape=input_shape)
  negative_example = Input(shape=input_shape)
  anchor_example = Input(shape=input_shape)

  embedding_network = create_embedding_network(input_shape)

  positive_embedding = embedding_network(positive_example)
  negative_embedding = embedding_network(negative_example)
  anchor_embedding = embedding_network(anchor_example)

  merged_output = concatenate([anchor_embedding, positive_embedding, negative_embedding])
  loss = Lambda(triplet_loss, (1,))(merged_output)

  model = Model(inputs=[anchor_example, positive_example, negative_example],
              outputs=loss)
  model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=Adam())

  return model



def create_embedding_network(input_shape):
  input_shape = Input(input_shape)
  x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(input_shape)
  x = PReLU()(x)
  x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3))(x)
  x = PReLU()(x)

  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
  model = Model(inputs=input_shape, outputs=x)
  return model
```

Every image is read using:

```
imageio.imread(imagePath, pilmode="RGB")
```

And the shape of each image:

```
(1024, 1024, 3)
```

Then i use my own triplet method (just creating 3 sets of anchor, positive and negative)

```
triplets = get_triplets(data)
triplets.shape
```

The shape is (number of examples, triplet, x_image, y_image, number of channels 
 (RGB)):

```
(20, 3, 1024, 1024, 3)
```

Then i use the build_model function:

```
model = build_model((1024, 1024, 3))
```

And the problem starts here:

```
model.fit(triplets, y=np.zeros(len(triplets)), batch_size=1)
```

For this line of code when i'm trying to train my model i'm getting this error:

[image: error]

For more details, my code is in this [collab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13CoIoWNsb0MStzDincvZL4ydUD2thLt0)

The pictures i used can be found in this [Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M7sgzAjmFfTkUjaXI-WMT5MS0Fnl5X50?usp=sharing)
For this to run seamlessly - place this folder under

> My Drive/Colab Notebooks/images/

Comment: you should feed your model with  a list of size 3 so that each element of this list will be in shape of (?, 1024, 1024, 3).

Comment: But if i send only a list of size 3 - how will it train all my data? 
Right now i'm sending 20 lists of size 3 (this is my data)  

EDIT - if i'm changing the call to only one triplet i'm getting the following error:  


    `Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1024, 1024, 3)  `


I updated the Collab notebook with this error

Comment: you send list of size 3 because your model need 3 input as it's input and on the other hand (according to your question) each of your input should be in shape of (? 1024, 1024, 3) where the `?` shows the batch size.

Comment: WOW ! 
I reshaped each image shape to (-1, 1024, 1024, 3) and now i can run the code with only a single triplet.
Is it possible in this concept to run all my data at once?
Or should i do it with for loop ?

Comment: Normally you do batch descent, this means you take a list of ~32 triplets and run your model on the mean gradient of those samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone also struggling

My problem was actually the dimension of each observation. 
By changing the dimension as suggested in the comments

```
(?, 1024, 1024, 3)
```

The colab notebook updated with the solution

P.s - i also changed the size of the pictures to 256 * 256 so that the code will run much faster on my pc.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, mark it as the solution.

Comment: Yes, that one soled it. I needed to wait 2 days to mark it as answer.